# Plot label disappearing in R

Tags: r, plot, axis

I plot my data first and then I add the axes. On my Y-axis the -10 isn't being placed next to the tick mark as it should. It is the only one doesn't appear. When my label font was set to 1.5 it was working. Now when set at 2 it does not work.

```
plot(opYcenter$V1, opYcenter$V2, xlab = "Time (days)", ylab = "RV (m/s)", axes = FALSE, cex.lab=2, cex = .5)


pos3= c(0,2000, 4000,6000,8000,10000)
stuff3 <- c("0","2000","4000","6000","8000","10000")
axis(side = 1,
 at = pos3,
 labels = stuff3 ,
 tck=-.025, 
 cex.axis =2,
 lwd =2)
pos4 =c(-15,-10,-5,0,5,10,15)
stuff4 = c("-15","-10","-5", "0","5","10","15")
axis(side = 2,
 at = pos2,
 labels = stuff2 ,
 tck=-.025, 
 cex.axis =2, //this part was working at 1.5
 lwd =2)
```

[image]

How do I fix this problem ? thanks!

Comment: Please provide some data that reproduces this problem so that we can do a better job of diagnosing it.

Comment: Not enough space for -10 to fit. Either reduce font size, ask for fewer labels, or make your graph larger

Comment: @RichardTelford, How would I make the graphic larger? would that be with ylim?

Comment: `x11(height = 8, width = 7)` for example. If you are on a mac you might have to use `quartz()`

Comment: try changing gap.axis to something small in your axis call. e.g. `axis(..., gap.axis = .1)`. Otherwise, you can specify the text using `text()` or `mtext()` and letters will just overlap instead of disappearing.